# Is there an improved version of "pick" that will work with filenames with spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, filenames, quoting, command-substitution

Is there a version of the pick script that will work properly with spaces in the filenames?

This is a tricky question—pick is trivial to enhance to work with spaces in filenames, but the output is just the filenames—with no indication of where a fillename begins or ends.

My goal is to be able to say something like

```
for i in `pick .??*` ; do ... ; done
```

But that is, as far as I can tell, hopeless; even using the `$()` syntax instead of the backticks, how do you get the filenames intact from the selection to the processing?

The only tool I can think of that comes close is `xargs -0`, which lets me have arbitrary names -- but I don't know how to interface to that except from `find -0`.

EDIT: Pick is a script that takes a bunch of files, and asks you which ones you want or don't want.

See
http://examples.oreilly.de/english_examples/upt3/split/pick
for a sample. It's not complicated, but if you don't know how to redirect inside a shell script, or have never seen that construct before, it will be a surprise.

And yes, it outputs one filename per line.

Comment: What is the `pick` script and what does it do? I have never heard of it

Comment: Information added to the problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pick` outputs of filename per line, you can set `IFS` to contain a newline only. Eg (in bash):

```
saved_ifs=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(pick .??*) ; do ... ; done
IFS=$saved_ifs
```

This will allow your filenames to contain spaces and tabs, of course if they contain newlines there will still be a problem. You may also want to consider disabling globbing if there are any filenames with glob characters (eg `*` or `?`). Use `set -f` to disable and `set +f` to reenable.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -name "* *" -type f -exec rename 's/ /_/g' {} +
```

**Replace the spaces in your filenames with "_".**

Then use pick.

*Rationale:* Spaces in file names are typically considered a non-standard file naming convention. Successful I.T. is about doing things the same way every time, reminiscent of Sun Tzu's art of war: *pick your battles carefully.*

Comment: Sadly, I cannot control the names that will be used by other programs.